# ASP.NET website adjustable width

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, width

I am using a CSS template to create a website and everything is appearing as a fixed size. How may I adjust everything so that the size of the items adjust to the size of the screen please so that it stretches to the entire width of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use percentages in your `width` properties instead of fixed-size units like pixels or ems.